# Vim: How to use the local arglist?

Tags: vim

If I run `:argl foo bar baz` file `foo` is opened for editing and my arglist (returned by `:args`) is `[foo] bar baz`.  If I then run `:next` I get brought to `bar`, but my arglist disappears (`:args` returns empty).  If I navigate to the alternate buffer I return to `foo` and my arglist is restored.  This behavior is very confusing to me - it suggests that local arglists are local to the buffer rather than local to the window.  How is this useful?  What am I missing here?

Side note: When I return to `foo` via the alternate buffer, I am not considered to be editing a file in the arglist, and `:args` returns `foo bar baz`.  I need to use `:first` to be back in the list and have `:args` return `[foo] bar baz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I run `:argl foo bar baz` file `foo` is opened for editing and my arglist (returned by `:args`) is `[foo] bar baz`.

Normal.

> If I then run `:next` I get brought to `bar`,

Still normal.

> but my arglist disappears (`:args` returns empty).

Hmm, this is getting weird.

> If I navigate to the alternate buffer I return to `foo` and my arglist is restored.

What?

> This behavior is very confusing to me

And very abnormal.

> it suggests that local arglists are local to the buffer rather than local to the window.

The local argument list is local to the window. What you describe is either a bug or some mistake in your configuration.

> How is this useful?

It's not and it shouldn't happen. Try again with `$ vim -Nu NONE`.

[image: arglist]

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this might be something peculiar in my vimrc.  Maybe a misbehaving plugin.  I'll investigate a bit more.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm using an autocmd that calls mkview and saving the argument list.